# Calculate wrong amount in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with some records now want to repeat this table content with some logic. I have two date start date and termination date, means record start from start_date and end on termination date, it will working fine but problem is calculate amount on it, 
Logic is amount calculation formula

```
basesalary / 12 * ( SUTARate / 100 ) * ( x.num+1)
```

if this amount is less than `SUTAMaximumAmount` this amount is used, else 0. And one more thing if amount will be remain and year is complete then restart calculation from next year.. x.num is temporary  table which hold 90 number from 1 to 90

Table

```
 BaseSalary|  S_Date  |  T_Date     | SUTARate| SUTAMaximumAmount |A_S_Percent
   48000   | 7-1-2013 |  3-15-2015  | 1.1     | 300               | 5
```

My result is

```
     DAte                     amount
2013-07-01 00:00:00.000         44
2013-08-01 00:00:00.000         44
2013-09-01 00:00:00.000         44
2013-10-01 00:00:00.000         44
2013-11-01 00:00:00.000         44
2013-12-01 00:00:00.000         44
2014-01-01 00:00:00.000         36
2014-02-01 00:00:00.000         -8
2014-03-01 00:00:00.000        -52
2014-04-01 00:00:00.000        -96
2014-05-01 00:00:00.000       -140
2014-06-01 00:00:00.000       -184
2014-07-01 00:00:00.000       -228
2014-08-01 00:00:00.000       -272
2014-09-01 00:00:00.000       -316
2014-10-01 00:00:00.000       -360
2014-11-01 00:00:00.000       -404
2014-12-01 00:00:00.000       -448
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000       -492
2015-02-01 00:00:00.000       -536
2015-03-01 00:00:00.000       -580
```

and I want result like this

```
Date       |  Amount
7-1-2013       44
8-1-2013       44
9-1-2013       44
10-1-2013      44
11-1-2013      44
12-1-2013      44
1-1-2014       44
2-1-2014       44
3-1-2014       44
4-1-2014       44
5-1-2014       44
6-1-2014       44
7-1-2014       36
1-1-2015       44
2-1-2015       44
3-1-2015       44
```

Query

```
SELECT dateadd(M, (x.num),d.StartDate) AS TheDate,            

Round( case when ((convert(float,d.SUTARate)/100* convert(integer,d.BaseSalary) / 12)*(x.num+1)) <=CONVERT(money,d.SUTAMaximumAmount)       
then (convert(float,d.SUTARate)/100* convert(integer,d.BaseSalary)* / 12)       
else (CONVERT(money,d.SUTAMaximumAmount)-((convert(float,d.SUTARate)/100* (convert(integer,d.BaseSalary) / 12)*x.num)))*Power((1+convert(float,d.AnnualSalaryIncreasePercent)/100),Convert(int,x.num/12)) end, 2) AS Amount,         
FROM #Table AS x,  myTbl AS d            
WHERE (x.num >= 0) AND (x.num <= (DateDiff(M, d.StartDate, d.TerminationDate)) )
```

temporary  table

```
create TABLE #Table (               
num int NOT NULL,              
);               
;WITH Nbrs ( n ) AS (              
    SELECT 0 UNION ALL              
    SELECT 1 + n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < 99 )              
    INSERT #Table(num)              
    SELECT n FROM Nbrs              
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 99 )
```

this table used as x in above query

Comment: Please provide sample data? more than 1 record?

Comment: this is only data i have and i'm getting result from this querry only @nrathaus

Comment: What do you mean? just show us raw data in the table you are using as `#Table` in your SQL and `myTbl`

Comment: use convert(varchar(10), Date, 120) to get date like YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: @nrathaus: I added concept of #Table

Comment: @Sohail: i'm not want date format i want resultant mentioned in querry

Comment: There is some sort of miscommunication, what is your issue? the data being displayed? the returned value ? in any case, it is hard to help you without sample data

Comment: @nrathaus: just need logic for stop at last end and restart it from new year

Comment: Ok, I don't know how to do what you are asking blindly. Maybe someone else can

Comment: You may review your parenthesis order in formula.

Answer (score 0):

I created [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c413d/13).

```
-- Numbers table is probably a good idea
WITH Nbrs ( num ) AS 
(              
    SELECT 0 UNION ALL              
    SELECT 1 + num FROM Nbrs WHERE num < 99 
)

-- All columns, except for 'num' come from myTbl
SELECT dateadd(M, (num),S_Date) AS TheDate,
Round( 
  CASE 
  WHEN (SUTARate / 100) * (BaseSalary / 12) <= SUTAMaximumAmount
  THEN (SUTARate / 100) * (BaseSalary / 12)
  ELSE 0
  END
, 2) As Amount
-- This may be the number you were trying to multiply
,DatePart(Month, dateadd(M, (num),S_Date)) As PotentialMultiiplier
FROM Nbrs AS x,  myTbl AS d            
WHERE (num >= 0) 
AND (num <= (DateDiff(M, S_Date, T_Date)) )
```

I am not entirely sure what your goal is, but you are probably on the right track with a numbers table. Because the result you are going for does not change much over time (i.e., nearly every month has an amount of $44), it is difficult to determine the correct code for the query. So, I recommend you provide a different set of data for better result-checking.

If you fiddle with the SQL in the provided link, you can re-post with better code, and then we can better solve your issue.